# Ler e imprimir uma sequência de 21 dígitos

Tags: c

Eu quero introduzir uma sequência de 21 números e guardá-la num array, e depois disso quero imprimir a sequência que guardei no array.

Este é o meu código:

```
void testa_nib () {

    int i=0,c=0;
    int nib[21];
    for (i=0;i<22;i++) {
        c=getchar();
        c=c-'0';
        nib[i] = c;
    }

    for (i=0;i<=21;i++){
        printf ("%d",nib[i]);
    }

int main() {

    testa_nib();
    return 0;
}
```

Este é o meu input:

> 123443211234567890127

Este é o meu output:

> -38123443211234567890127

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOPT. :)
Por favor traduza a sua pergunta, esta é uma comunidade em português, ou considere postar no site inglês.

Comment: pensei que nao estava no SOPT, desculpa

Answer (score 1):

Uma coisa a se notar é que você está tentando atribuir ao valor de um inteiro um char, usando a função `getchar`. Ao invés disso, use o `scanf`. Exemplo

```
#include <stdio.h>

void testa_nib() {
    int i = 0, c = 0;
    int nib[21];

    for (i = 0; i < 22; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &nib[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i <= 21; i++) {
        printf("%d", nib[i]);
    }

}

int main() {
    testa_nib();
    return 0;
}
```

Veja funcionando no onlinegdb: https://onlinegdb.com/HJJC02dH4

Comment: E usei o getchar para poder pôr como input aquele número todo sem espaços entre cada número. Usando o scanf eu só conseguia fazer com q a funçao funcionasse se desse como input: 1 2 3 4 4 3 2 1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 7

Comment: Isso não iria funcionar. A função `getchar` lê apenas um caractere digitado, todos os outros seriam ignorados. https://www.dcc.fc.up.pt/~nam/aulas/0001/pi/slides/slipi0010/node9.html

Comment: mas funcionou, sinceramente tb fiquei um bcd na dúvida por causa disso